# Resolving ambiguity in template overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a heavily-templated C++17 library in which I need to define a template structure for various types. For the sake of the example, let's say that I need specializations for a set of types (e.g. strings, integral types, etc.), and a specialization for any *class* (i.e. anything satisfying `std::is_class<T>`) for which I don't yet have a specialization.

I currently have the following code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct A;

template<typename String>
struct A<String,
         std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_same_v<
                std::decay_t<String>,
                std::string>
         || std::is_same_v<
                std::decay_t<String>,
                std::string_view>>>
{
    static void f(String&&) {
        std::cout << "In String specialization" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename Object>
struct A<Object,
         std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_class_v<std::decay_t<Object>>>>
{
    static void f(Object&&) {
        std::cout << "In Object specialization" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void g(T&& t) {
    A<T>::f(t);
}

int main() {
    std::string str;
    g(str);
}
```

This code does not compile, because `std::string` is a class and therefore matches both specializations. I get an `error: ambiguous partial specializations of 'A<std::string &>'`.

What would be the idiomatic way of resolving this kind of problem, i.e. defining specializations that may overlap with previous specializations but should be given a lower priority?

Comment: C++20 allows ordering specializations. Are you limited to C++17?

Comment: Kind of, using C++17 is a choice of mine, to make the library more broadly usable, as I know many people are still far from even using C++17 (at work I'm stuck with C++14, for instance).

Answer (score 4):

You could negate the condition for the more general `is_class` case:

```cpp
// helper trait:
template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_stringish_v = std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string> ||
                                       std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string_view>;
```

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct A;

template <typename String>
struct A<String, std::enable_if_t<is_stringish_v<String>>> {
    static void f(String&&) {
        std::cout << "In String specialization" << std::endl;
    }
};

// in here, you negate it:
template <typename Object>
struct A<Object, std::enable_if_t<!is_stringish_v<Object>&&
                                  std::is_class_v<std::decay_t<Object>>>> 
{
    static void f(Object&&) {
        std::cout << "In Object specialization" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a good solution for you in the general sense, but in the example in your question, you can simply do:

```
template<typename Object>
struct A<Object,
         std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_class_v<std::decay_t<Object>> && 
            !std::is_same_v<std::string> && !std::is_same_v<std::string_view>>>
{ ... };
```

(might need some `std::decay_t`s in there I guess, and you can probably factor out that test).

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/62G3n5JkUwZtlMwM)

Also, since you're on C++17, `if constexpr` might provide a cleaner solution than lots of SFINAE trickery, which has always been a bit of a hack, IMO.

No chance of moving to C++20, I suppose?

Comment: Negating type traits is what I was going to use, but I have a bunch of other specialization (integral types, booleans, float types, various strings, various other custom objects, etc.). I have defined a custom type trait that says "none of those types" and keep adding types to it. That works fine until I forget to add a type.

Comment: But, presumably, you then get a compiler error and can add it in.  Anyway, @ted's is a better answer than mine (although the principle is the same).